# Connecting two ethernet PHY's (KSZ8051RNLU) in RMII back toback configuration

Tags: ethernet, phy, rmii

I would like to to connect the KSZ8051RNLU in a loopback configuration with itself, I have read that this is possible with other PHY's. Does the KSZ8051RNLU have this capability? Will it auto-configure itself if it can do this?

Has anyone does this before and does the below diagram look correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fudTep.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that is not a loopback configuration as it means connecting a single PHY to itself.

I assume you mean you want to connect two PHYs in back-to-back configuration to make an Ethernet repeater.

The data sheet boasts you can connect two PHYs in back-to-back configuration to make a copper repeater.

Section 3.4 of the datasheet has a connection diagram how to connect them, and how to set the configuration straps for this mode.

(Disclaimer, I've not used this PHY in PHY-to-PHY mode).

Comment: I'm going to use it for a loopback test